# Matlab hangs while generating mex-file

Tags: matlab, mex, matlab-deployment, matlab-figure

Matlab hangs when I am trying to generate a mex-file. When I run the program like normal everything works and when I try to generate a mex-file matlab gets to the end of the code but nothing happens after that. I have understood that it might have something to do with the figures. I read somewhere that it calls `mclWaitForFiguresToDie` but I have not understood how to fix it.

One figure should be displayed but it is not displayed while generating the mex-code.

Comment: This might be compiler-, OS- and/or MATLAB version-dependent. It would be useful to know which compiler, which OS and which MATLAB version you are using.

Comment: Hello. I have been able to compile mex-files with the same setup so I think it has to do with the code. I run win7, Matlab 2011b. I have tried with two compilers: Microsoft Software Development Kit (SDK) 7.1 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. The result is the same..

Comment: So are you telling the mex file doesn't work as expected, or that you can't create the mex file?

Comment: It is not possible to create the mex-file. The building of the mex-file hangs. It works with earlier versions of the same code but I have changed about 1500 lines since then...

It does not report errors but it just hangs without finishing the build

Comment: Have you tried compiling the Mex file without using Matlab ?  Mex files are really just DLLs.  Try poking around inside the Mex opts file to figure things out, or use the verbose option (-v) in your mex command to see what compilation flags Matlab uses.

Comment: It was very strange. I needed to comment (so that they were not run) the plot-commands, even those that were not run made it hang if they were not commented.